# Integrate Angular2 app into existing site

Tags: angular

I build a test application in Angular2 (RC4) with Angular Cli.
The application is really simple with 3 components and 3 routes.
I build the application in `prod` with Angular Cli.
Now I want to integrate this app into existing site (for example on about page) in a way that it wouldn't effect the router of my site.
The idea is to have this Angular2 App like a feature/plugin on my site.

More less the effect which I want to achieve is similar to Angular2 application written in Fiddler, Plunker and etc. (you can see the app in result window and changing the state is not changing the url of the browser tab).  [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/smUy1twVS8v5YBdDa0c9/)

Definitely I don't want to use `<iframe>` for this.

I was looking for some information in Google but I couldn't find anything.
The nearest suggestion which I found was:

```
... <!--Existing site -->    
<section class="here"></section>
<script>$('.here').load('angular2App/index.html'); //the index.html of build anguar2 app</script>
```

This is not working and require a lot of modification of all `href`, `src` and etc

My router(`app.routes.ts`) looks like this:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
    }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

How can I integrate a Angular2 app into existing site?

Comment: At some point, won't you need to hook up the router of the existing app to tell it to redirect to the Angular2 pages?

Comment: The comparison to Plunker is pointless, because it solely relies on iframes. Please, specify which kind of routing the existing app has, which kind of routing Angular SPA has and how they should behave together. Most likely you want to use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html), but the everything else is a mystery.

Comment: The existing site is build in C# and I want to include my Angular2 app on it.

Comment: I think you need a custom `LocationStrategy`. For example a derivative of `HashLocationStrategy` that doesn't update the URL bar.

Comment: For now I even cannot make my angular2 app working like a plugin...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I include the app on my site. Now I have to fix the `LocationStrategy` issue.Do you have some example of custom `LocationStrategy`?

Comment: I don't have an example. I'd copy `HashLocationStrategy` and modify it so it updates only an internal array instead of the browser history.

Comment: We had a similar problem and the solution we chose was to have a separate Apache Server map / redirect all URLs to existing app and new angular app. This is a powerful solution but you need to manually maintain different URLs